# Why pass by refrance makes notice message in php?

Tags: php, variables, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to use the following function in PHP to echo the variable if it's already been set or echo the alternate text:

```
function _echo(&$var, $alt = ''){
    if ( isset($var) ){
        echo $var;
    } else {
        echo $alt;
    }
}
```

And the following code to call the function. Note that $plan is not defined before:

```
<input type="text" name="test" value="<?= _echo($plan['program']) ?>">
```

But it triggers:

> Notice: Undefined index: program in [file] on line [line]

I tried the following code to find out the problem and it was unexpected, $plan was defined when function is being called:

```
var_dump($plan);
<input type="text" name="test" value="<?= _echo($plan['test']) ?>">
var_dump($plan);
```

And the output was:

> Notice: Undefined variable: plan in [file] on line [line] Notice:
>
> Undefined index: program in [file] on line [line] >> Here NULL was echoed
>
> array(1) { ["program"]=> NULL }

What is the problem exactly and how can I make such a function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in passing argument by reference, but rather in referencing array index that does not exist or variable that does not exist. You would have to use `isset()`:

```
<input type="text" name="test"
value="<?= _echo(isset($plan['program']) ? $plan['program']: '') ?>">
```

Comment: Well isn't there ANY method to implement such validation in the function itself?